# Can I get some help in clicking buttons and getting response

Tags: javascript, html

I am VERY (can't emphasize that enough) new to html,css,javascript. Can someone explain a little bit why this isn't working please.

```js
var button1 = "button1";

function buttonPress();

if (buttonPress == "button1") {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You pressed button one";
} {
  return true;
} else

  (buttonPress == "button2" {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You pressed button two";
    };
    return false;
  }
```

```html
<button class="button button1" id="button1" onclick="buttonPress();">clickhere</button>
<button class="button button2" id="button2" onclick="buttonPress();">clickhere</button>
<center>
  <p id="demo" </p>
</center>
```

Comment: You have multiple typo error.

Comment: I don't want this to sound rude, but if you are THAT new to HTML, CSS and JavaScript, you should try going a little bit further in your studies before starting to ask questions. Your original question is not understandable. Is not even readable and makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, both HTML and Javascript syntax in your code is very messed up. That should be sorted out first, before you continue (check console for error messages)

Next your `buttonPress` function receives no information about which button was pressed. You can fix that by sending to it the `this` object:
`buttonPress(this)` and at receiving end: `function buttonPress(button) {`

And finally, since variable `button` now contain the HTML element of the pressed button, you'll need check it's ID:
`if (button.id == "button1") {`

> 

```js
function buttonPress(button) {
  if (button.id == "button1") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You pressed button one";
    return true;
  }
  if (button.id == "button2") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You pressed button two";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button button1" id="button1" onclick="buttonPress(this);">clickhere</button>
<button class="button button2" id="button2" onclick="buttonPress(this);">clickhere</button>
<center>
  <p id="demo"> </p>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var button1 = "button1";

function buttonPress();

if (buttonPress == "button1") {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You pressed button one";
} {
  return true;
} else

(buttonPress == "button2" {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You pressed button two";
};
return false;
}
```

**Reasons for failure:**

The function definition `function buttonPress();` is incorrect. The function should follow the pattern:

```
function buttonPress(){

};
```

(caveat: unless using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or anonymous type functions)

The logic of the function should be within the curly braces of the function body.

```
function buttonPress(){
    /*
        logic here
    */
};
```

The variable `buttonPress` does not exist so the logic `if (buttonPress == "button1")` is flawed initially because of that.

There is a mismatch of curly braces in the above code and the `else` condition looks like it ought to actually be an `else if( ..conditions.. ){ ..actions.. }` type thing.

The `p` element was missing the closing `>` after the ID declaration.

To use the original code (with some rewrites) would work if the `event` were supplied as an argument and used to determine which button was clicked.

```js
function buttonPress(event){
    if(event.target.id=='button1'){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You pressed button one";
        return true;
    }else if(event.target.id=='button2'){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You pressed button two";
         return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="button button1" id="button1" onclick="buttonPress(event);">clickhere</button>
<button class="button button2" id="button2" onclick="buttonPress(event);">clickhere</button>
<center>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</center>
```

You can simplify things a little by using an externally registered event handler and using the `event` to aid determining which element triggered the event.

```js
let counter={};

document.querySelectorAll('button.button').forEach( bttn=>{
  counter[bttn.id]=0;
  
  bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    counter[this.id]=counter[this.id]+1;
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent='You pressed "'+this.id+'" a total of '+counter[this.id]+' times'
  });
  
})
```

```html
<button class="button button1" id='button-1'>click here</button>
<button class="button button2" id='button-2'>click here</button>
<center>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</center>
```